Call method of TextBlock WPF in user class inherited from RemoteUserControl
I want to write my Visual Studio Extension Debugger Visualizer.
I started to use new , modern Debugger visualizer (which use DebuggerVisualizerProvider class). And i get in problem. I need to Add WebView2 control in XAML and i need to call NavigateToString method from code. But... This type of VS project use MVVM pattern and there is no method to access WebView2 control from code by Name... yes.... And i need to find a way how to call method from code. Please, help.
P.S. i want to say that i make a search and spand many days and i find many solutions, but the did't work (((
What i find is (XAML code in MyUserControl.xaml file):
<wv:WebView2 Source="https://www.google.ru">
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <local:WebView2Custombehavior MethodName="ExecuteScriptAsync"  ExecuteMethod="{Binding ExecuteMethod}" MethodParameter="{Binding MethodParameter}"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>

And a create class WebView2Custombehavior in which i register three DependencyProperty: MethodName, ExecuteMethod,MethodParameter.And i create MyModel class. And in WPF this code works, but in Visual Studio Extension project (which Visual Studi Extensibility Extension with VSSDK Compatibility) i get error:
Cannot set unknown member '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behavior}Interaction.Bevahiors'.
Strange things...
Maybe somehow add this code in resources:
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
<local:WebView2Custombehavior MethodName="ExecuteScriptAsync"  ExecuteMethod="{Binding ExecuteMethod}" MethodParameter="{Binding MethodParameter}"/>

</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
Please help.

Hi @jin15,  if it possible, could you provide a Minimal, Reproducible demo to help me better understand your scenario?

I find a solution. Thanks

Glad to hear that you have found a solution. If possible, you could add an answer. This will help other users who has the same issue and someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem. Just a reminder;.)
